# File not found while creating file in Python3 in a cron job. (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2])

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cron, debian, filenotfounderror

After I've updated my system, a weird error appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File /home/username/bin/my_application.py, line 116, in <module>
    with open(lock_file, 'x'):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/run/user/1000/running_application.lock'
```

Line 116+117 look like this:

```
with open(lock_file, 'x'):
    print("Lockfile " + lock_file + " created")
```

The path of the lockfile is defined like this:

```
lock_file = '/run/user/' + str(os.getuid()) + '/running_application.lock'
```

The uid is always 1000 (if triggered by cron or by hand).

I am trying to create a file only to avoid to run this script several times at the same time. It will be triggered in a cron job (crontab -e) on a Debian 11 bullseye server. Before this line, a routine will be triggered to wait until the file doesn't exist anymore or if x minutes are over to exit.

It always worked and if I trigger this script **by hand**, it still works. But out of the nowhere it doesn't work if it's triggered over the cron job.

And I don't understand the error at all. How can Python expect a file, if the file doesn't exist and have to be created?

I already tried it with the 'w' option, but the same error appears.

And I don't know what to do anymore, because this script works perfectly if it's triggered by hand.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the environment variable inside your cronjob

in your cronjob you could add something like `*/5 * * * * export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 && /usr/bin/python3 /home/username/bin/my_application.py`

you can also use an absolut path for your lock file `lock_file = '/home/username/locks/running_application.lock'`

Also check the permissions, maybe the user running the cron dont have the right permission to create the lock file ?